# parse password reset key from emailed weblink

Tags: php, html, email, url

Since I switched to using hashed passwords in my demo website, I needed to provide a way reset forgotten passwords.

I've got the pages and php setup to send an email with a url+key that the user will need in order to setup new password.  The email contains the url to click on and the link brings the user to the reset password page.

The part I'm having a bit of trouble with is pulling the key information from the url so I can use it to compare to the key generated from the reset password submission.  The database correctly inserts the key when the forgot password form is submitted.

I'm assuming I need to use parse_url to extract this information from the link but I'm not quite sure how to pull only the key information from the link.

I think PHP_URL_QUERY gets me to the correct part of the URL.  From here I'm not quite sure what to do next since PHP_URL_QUERY gives me all of this:

key='.$2y$10$q53hrjswTfXnkxg8QeJysezbBi91t4yJcbV9bH3addOSiotr6kE1

when what I really want is this to do the comparison:

'.$2y$10$q53hrjswTfXnkxg8QeJysezbBi91t4yJcbV9bH3addOSiotr6kE1

Here's the code I've got right now....

```
<?php
require_once '../php/connect.php';

function URL() {
  $purl = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") {
      $purl .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
  return $purl;
}

$key = parse_url($purl, PHP_URL_QUERY)


$qry = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM planner WHERE rkey = '$key'");
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);

    }
}
```

I think I just need a way to strip the key= part from the rest, but I'm not sure that is quite right.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `$_GET`?

Comment: So something like . htmlspecialchars($_GET["key"]) . ;    ?

Comment: Definitely don't do what you're doing. It's not secure. Use this guide: https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/09/untangling-forget-me-knot-secure-account-recovery-made-simple

Comment: You need to learn about escaping.  HTML-escaping a SQL query makes no sense and is still insecure.

Comment: Thanks for the insight folks...this is my first swing at this particular piece of web design.  I'll take a good look at the guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working with the following....this is just a start.  Thanks again everyone.

```
<?php
require_once '../php/connect.php';

$sub = htmlspecialchars($_GET["key"]);
$ser = "'.";
$rkey = str_replace($ser,'',$sub);

$qry = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM planner WHERE rkey = '$rkey'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($qry);

echo $row;

?>
```